# Is $x^2-ax+a^x-1$ real and less than $2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, quadratics

> Is $x^2-ax+a^x-1$ real and less than $2$?

I've begun with finding the discriminant of the function as for a function to be real it's domain needs to be real, but there I'm stuck with another quadratic equation, $a^2-4a^x-4$ how should I proceed to solve this.

Comment: What is $a$?  The discriminant isn't going to help you because the "constant" term in fact varies with respect to $x$.  But if you take $f'(x)$ I think you'll quickly see what's going on.  Or just consider what happens to the expression at large values of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

As @Robert Shore commented, consider the function
$$f(x)=x^2-ax+a^x-3$$
Since there is no restriction on $x$, we must consider $a>0$.

For this function
$$f'(x)=2x-a+a^x\log(a) \qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x)=2+a^x\log^2(a)$$

The first derivative cancels at
$$x_*=\frac{a}{2}-\frac{W\left(\frac{1}{2} a^{a/2} \log ^2(a)\right)}{\log (a)}> 0 \quad \forall a >0$$ where $W(\cdot)$ is Lambert funtion.

$$f(x_*)=\frac{W\left(\frac{1}{2} a^{a/2} \log ^2(a)\right) \left(W\left(\frac{1}{2} a^{a/2}
   \log ^2(a)\right)+2\right)}{\log ^2(a)}-\frac{a^2}{4}-3< 0 \quad \forall a >0$$
$$f''(x_*)=2 \left(W\left(\frac{1}{2} a^{a/2} \log ^2(a)\right)+1\right)> 0 \quad \forall a >0$$

So, $x_*$ corresponds to a minimum of the function.

So $f(x) >0$ as soon as $x$ is greater than the solution of $f(x)=0$. The problem is that this solution does not show analytical expression even using special functions. This would require numerical methods.

**Edit**

For the solution of $f(x)=0$, we can try *approximations* using Taylor expansion around $x=x_*$. This gives
$$f(x)=f(x_*)+\frac 12 f''(x_*) (x-x_*)^2+O((x-x_*)^3)$$ and then the *estimate* of the two roots
$$x_\pm=x_* \pm \sqrt{-2 \frac{f(x_*)}{f''(x_*)}}$$
which is not too bad as shown in the table below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 a   & x_-^{est} & x_-^{sol} & x_+^{est} & x_+^{sol} \\
 0.5 & -0.903913 &  -0.864409 & 1.89548 &  1.92296 \\
 1.0 & -1.000000 &  -1.000000 & 2.00000 &  2.00000 \\
 1.5 & -0.936168 &  -0.947495 & 1.93926 &  1.92477 \\
 2.0 & -0.812208 &  -0.856835 & 1.82693 &  1.76912 \\
 2.5 & -0.687117 &  -0.766724 & 1.71781 &  1.62278 \\
 3.0 & -0.578848 &  -0.686196 & 1.62603 &  1.50937 \\
 3.5 & -0.489248 &  -0.616558 & 1.55184 &  1.42444 \\
 4.0 & -0.415757 &  -0.556942 & 1.49223 &  1.36021 \\
 4.5 & -0.355212 &  -0.505957 & 1.44407 &  1.31065 \\
 5.0 & -0.304866 &  -0.462221 & 1.40477 &  1.27158
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using these estimates as $x_0$, Newton method should converge quite fast using, as usual,
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac {f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ In the present case
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{a^{x_n} (x_n \log (a)-1)+x_n^2+3}{a^{x_n} \log (a)-a+2 x_n}$$ Using it for a bad case $a=5$, the iterates would be

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & -0.30486609 \\
 1 & -0.47148352 \\
 2 & -0.46224714 \\
 3 & -0.46222053
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.40477251 \\
 1 & 1.28842795 \\
 2 & 1.27188642 \\
 3 & 1.27157994 \\
 4 & 1.27157984
\end{array}
\right)$$